# How to test editing a field from Cypress todo app?

Tags: cypress

I'm new to Cypress and I'm using their `todo app` example, I want to test the fact that we can edit a field ( double click on it, type, validate)

```
// use the example from Cypress for the todo app

describe('example to-do app', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io/todo')
  })

  it('can edit a todo items', () => {
    // add it
    cy.contains('Pay electric bill')
        .parent()
        .dblclick()
        .type(' v2')
        .type('Cypress.io{enter}')


    // control it
    cy.get('.todo-list li')
        .should('have.length', 2)
        .last()
        .should('have.text', 'Pay electric bill v2')
  })
})
```

The error I have is that the field isn't typeable but I don't know why it isn't because when I take a look after the `dbclick()` the field is editable

[image]
[image]

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming because the `.parent()` element of your `.contains('Pay electric bill')` is a `div`, and not the `input` element you want.

```html
<div class="view">
  <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
  <label>Pay electric bill</label>
  <button class="destroy todo-button"></button>
</div>
```

Instead of using `.parent()`, [try using `.sibling('input')`.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/siblings)

```js
cy.contains('Pay electric bill')
        .siblings('input')
        .dblclick()
        .type(' v2')
        .type('Cypress.io{enter}')
```